# Changing button's value doesn't visually appear until after delay

Tags: javascript, html

Running into some strange behaviour here. I have the following button element:

```
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Sign up now">
```

and it is wrapped in a form with some other inputs.
When I click this button, I want to change the value of the button first, wait 2 seconds, then change it back. Basically just trying to simulate some sort of processing going on.

Here's my JS:

```
button.onclick = function submitForm() {
    button.value="Submitting...";
    button.style.display = 'none';
    button.style.display = 'block';
    start = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() - start < 2000);
};
```

The thing is, I never see the value change to "Submitting..." until after the while loop finishes. But the line changing the value comes before the while loop, should it not run first, regardless of the presence of the while loop? It seems to work fine without the 2 second pause while loop.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Why not use setTimeout() which seems more appropriate instead of while loop.

Comment: So whats the while loop . Use setTimout() function. And in the function set the style?

Comment: @August I came across that in some online reading, but JS is async right? So if I use setTimeout()  won't it continue on to the next lines?

Comment: @CapnJack JS is single threaded (not full async) and your while loop will block execution but setTimeout is async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **JS is a single threaded programming language**

A loop will block the UI thread so you won't be able to see the changes.

Use `setTimeout(func,delay)` instead.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');

button.onclick = function () {
    
    button.value="Submitting...";

    setTimeout(function(){
            button.value = "Sign up now";
   },2000);
};
```

```html
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Sign up now">
```

Also you may wanna [Check this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: You've solved my problem so thanks. But just getting a little deeper for a sec, even though it's a single thread, why doesn't it finish completing the first line (changing my button's value) before moving on to the while loop?

Comment: Take a look at that video, and you'll understand how it works :)

Comment: Just finished watching that video; it was incredibly relevant to my question. I'm still wondering why though the UI doesn't update when I have that while loop going. Sure, it's blocking the stack, but should the UI have updated before this occurs? My guess is that in changing the button.value, I've started a series of child events that will be added to the stack soon, and by the time they are added to the stack, the while loop is in first, and thus blocking. Am I on the right track here? The area about what happens exactly after updating button.value is a little grey to me still.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking to do?
https://jsfiddle.net/vbz4n2fg/

```
button.onclick = function submitForm() {
    button.value="Submitting...";

    setTimeout(function(){ button.value="Sign up now"; }, 2000);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for I guess.

```js
button = document.getElementById('button');

button.onclick = function submitForm() {
    var initialValue = button.value;
    
    button.value = 'Submitting...';
    setTimeout(function(){
      button.value = initialValue;
    }, 2000);
    
};
```

```html
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Sign up now">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a input type="submit". 
Usually, this kind of button refresh the page, ignoring the rest of the javascript.
Try to change the input type to button, or use the button tag with the type button.

Comment: it will refresh the page only when it's inside a form, but that isn't the main question here.